# With skipper 2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT Spring Cloud dataflow Installation fails - Kubernetes & Local

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

[image: Spring Cloud Dataflow Install Guide]
[image: Skipper Exception]

```html
On downgrading to skipper springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:2.3.2.RELEASE, the install was successful.
```

Comment: Most likely a side effect from the recent changes to metadata labeling machinery. I added an issue to track it; see: [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#3926](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3926)

Comment: This has been identified as a bug and is already resolved. Please retry and let us know if you see any other issues.

Comment: Just tried, no luck. But this time I tried in Microk8s environment not sure whether it's environment causing problem. My observation is SCDF install on Microk8s is not smooth.

Comment: I tried downgrading to 2.3.2 RELEASE in Microk8s. The pod creation is stuck. In docker desktop with 2.3.2 I didn't see this issue.